# R: svmRadial not working properly in caret

Tags: r, svm, r-caret

I was trying to run the code from "Applied Predictive Modeling" book, the part about training SVM with radial kernel via caret "train" function.

I copied the code without any additions. The code ran without any errors, but results do not correspond to those written in the book. All probabilities are nearly the same and all objects are classified into one class. Here is this code:

```
library(caret)
data("GermanCredit")
GermanCredit <- GermanCredit[, -nearZeroVar(GermanCredit)]
# remove some other columns that do not add useful information
GermanCredit$CheckingAccountStatus.lt.0 <- NULL
GermanCredit$SavingsAccountBonds.lt.100 <- NULL
GermanCredit$EmploymentDuration.lt.1 <- NULL
GermanCredit$EmploymentDuration.Unemployed <- NULL
GermanCredit$Personal.Male.Married.Widowed <- NULL
GermanCredit$Property.Unknown <- NULL
GermanCredit$Housing.ForFree <- NULL

#Split the data into training (80%) and test sets (20%)
set.seed(100)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(GermanCredit$Class, p = .8)[[1]]
GermanCreditTrain <- GermanCredit[ inTrain, ]
GermanCreditTest  <- GermanCredit[-inTrain, ]

set.seed(1056)
svmFit <- train(Class ~ .,
           data = GermanCreditTrain,
           method = "svmRadial",
           preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
           tuneLength = 10,
           trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",                                        repeats = 5,
                                    classProbs = TRUE))
```

The output of the model is like this:

```
> svmFit
Support Vector Machines with Radial Basis Function Kernel 

800 samples
 41 predictor
  2 classes: 'Bad', 'Good' 

Pre-processing: centered (41), scaled (41) 
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 5 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 720, 720, 720, 720, 720, 720, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  C       Accuracy  Kappa      
    0.25  0.70025   0.006361713
    0.50  0.70025   0.006372290
    1.00  0.70025   0.006372290
    2.00  0.70075   0.008001058
    4.00  0.70100   0.009101928
    8.00  0.69950   0.004902168
   16.00  0.70050   0.006864093
   32.00  0.70025   0.006361713
   64.00  0.70050   0.007509254
  128.00  0.70050   0.007472237

Tuning parameter 'sigma' was held constant at a value of 0.01390712
Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
The final values used for the model were sigma = 0.01390712 and C = 4.
```

So, accuracy even doesn't change. I tried different sets of parameters, but results are the same.

Probabilities are almost the same for all samples: ~0.304 for "bad" class, ~0.695 for "good" (differences are only in fourth digit).

Results from the book are available here: https://github.com/cran/AppliedPredictiveModeling/blob/master/inst/chapters/04_Over_Fitting.Rout

They have

```
> svmFit
Support Vector Machines with Radial Basis Function Kernel 

800 samples
 41 predictors
  2 classes: 'Bad', 'Good' 

Pre-processing: centered, scaled 
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 5 times) 

Summary of sample sizes: 720, 720, 720, 720, 720, 720, ... 

Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  C     Accuracy  Kappa  Accuracy SD  Kappa SD
  0.25  0.744     0.362  0.0499       0.113   
  0.5   0.74      0.35   0.0516       0.117   
  1     0.746     0.348  0.0522       0.125   
  2     0.743     0.325  0.0467       0.116   
  4     0.744     0.322  0.0477       0.12    
  8     0.75      0.323  0.0464       0.13    
  16    0.745     0.302  0.0457       0.13    
  32    0.739     0.28   0.0451       0.126   
  64    0.743     0.284  0.0444       0.135   
  128   0.734     0.265  0.0445       0.124   

Tuning parameter 'sigma' was held constant at a value of 0.008918477
Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using  the largest     value.
The final values used for the model were sigma = 0.00892 and C = 8.
```

Moreover, entire class got such results, but the teacher, whose computer has older version of R, got correct results. So here is my question: is the problem in some changes in newer versions of R, caret, kernlab or something, or am I doing wrong with something else? How should this code be changed to achieve proper results? Caret version is 6.0-77.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the expected output (from the book?).

Comment: Added output and link to full text

Comment: Try using the current development version. There might be an issue with the latest version on CRAN.

Comment: Hello, @topepo! I've just installed dev version from github. It seems to be working fine. Thanks a lot.